# Select option value get undefined in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am just started work with node js. Right now I don't have enough idea about it. By using the route I can get 2 values from my ejs form. I don't get the value of selection option.

ejs code:

```html
<select class="form-control" name="skb">
                                       <option value="">Choose Password Category</option>
                                       <% if(records.length > 0){
                                        records.forEach(function(row){
                                        %>
                                       <option value="<%= row.passord_category %>"><%= row.password_cat %></option>
                                       <%  }) } %>
                                      </select>
```

js code:

```js
router.post('/add-new-password', checkLoginUser,function(req, res, next) {
  var loginUser=localStorage.getItem('loginUser');
var pass_cat= req.body.skb;  //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
var project_name= req.body.project_name;
var pass_details= req.body.pass_details;
console.log(pass_cat);
console.log(project_name);
console.log(pass_details);
  });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1JuV.png)

Comment: Try `req.body.skb`.  `skb` is the name of the select element.

Comment: I mention the same thing what you suggest..